Passing html to livewire custom component and modify it
I have a class-based volt component that shows a button and when the button is clicked it opens a modal. So far so good.
I would like to pass the button html when calling the component as a "slot" in order to let the user create their own custom button.
What im trying to do is just this:
<livewire:components.search-user>
    <button>Click me</button>
</livewire:components.search-user>

and in the component capture this html <button>Click me</button> and wrap it up in a div of my own to then display it.
Is this possible?
